# Add appointment to a specific calendar with Siri

Tags: calendar, siri

My default calendar is 'Home'. I want Siri to add appointments to my 'Work' calendar. I've tried telling Siri to "Move my appointment to the work calendar" but she merely changes the appointment location to "the work calendar". Is there a specific phrase that I can use to get her to understand what I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At this time Siri will only add events to your default calendar. You can make your work calendar the default calendar if you want to. You do this in Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars on your iPhone.

Comment: Siri doesn't seem to be honoring my default calendar - she'll just always add it to the most-recently added calendar regardless of my default calendar setting, at least in iOS 8. Any idea how to override this?